# Required latest record for a table for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT results.time_stamp,
results.result, results.note, tests.test
FROM results INNER JOIN tests
ON results.test_id = tests.id
```

I need to modify this to return only the the row with newest date for each distinct test_id. 
But I can't use MAX() because note and test are data type text

Comment: MAX wouldn't be the right thing to use anyway here. There would be no guarantee that the row with MAX (note) was the row with the highest timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `subquery` instead :

```
select r.*
from results r
where date = (select top 1 date
              from tests t 
              where t.id = r.test_id
              order by date desc
             );
```

If you want to return data from both tables then you can do the `JOIN` & use `row_number()` function instead :

```
select top 1 with ties r.*, t.test
from results r inner join 
     tests t
     on t.id = r.test_id
order by row_number() over (partition by r.test_id order by r.date desc);
```

Comment: NB: The Op wants records from the `tests` table too; and wants the max date *per test id*; not just the overall max date.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **[row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** inside an inner query to solve your problem.
However in case there are more than one row with same timestamp for an id this will only return one row.

```
select 
    time_stamp,result,note,test
from
(
SELECT 
    results.time_stamp,
    results.result, 
    results.note, 
    tests.test,
    rn=row__number() over( partition by results.test_id order by results.time_stamp desc)
FROM results 
    INNER JOIN tests
        ON results.test_id = tests.id

)
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cross apply answer:

```
SELECT 
    results.time_stamp,
    results.result, 
    results.note, 
    tests.test
FROM results
CROSS APPLY
(
    select top 1 *
    from tests t 
    where t.id = results.test_id
    order by date desc
) tests
```